# jQuery scrollTop lags on mobile browsers

Tags: jquery, performance, scroll, scrolltop, scrollto

I am working on a webpage and on the mobile version I use jQuery scrollTop to scroll to a certain section of the page when an element is clicked.

This is the code that I am using:

```
$('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $("#mobile-version").offset().top}, 5000);
```

The main problem happens when I use the page on a mobile device, the scrolling lags/glitches while on desktop browsers it works perfectly.

I also tried with a jQuery plugin (scrollTo) but the results are the same. I tried to disable the background of the page. remove content so it will be more lightweight but the lagging it's still there.

Any of you guys have any ideas of why this happens?

LIVE PAGE: [dev.hoej.dk](http://dev.hoej.dk)

Comment: What mobile device are you using for test? It seems like the device is not as powerful as page needs.

Comment: I am using a iphone 6 and iphone 6S

Comment: So there's another problem. I been using animation scrolls with iphones and it works perfectly even in iphone 5

Comment: Yes, that is why I tried to remove the background gradient and remove content from the page to make it more lightweight and the issue still persisted.

Comment: I can't help you because I don't have a device to test it, but I think is the animations and the svg images that causes this lost of performance

Comment: Thanks for trying anyway :)